# How does pattern-match driven logic look like in real world applications?

Tags: oop, pattern-matching

I stumbled across the following passage (while reading [PEP-3119](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/), but the question isn’t language-specific). Emphasis mine.

> In particular, there is often a need to process objects in a way that wasn't anticipated by the creator of the object class. It is not always the best solution to build in to every object methods that satisfy the needs of every possible user of that object. Moreover, **there are many powerful dispatch philosophies that are in direct contrast to the classic OOP requirement of behavior being strictly encapsulated within an object, examples being rule or pattern-match driven logic**.

I’m familiar with OOP: code structured around objects that mirror concepts or real-world entities, encapsulate states, and can be acted upon through methods.

How does rule or pattern-match driven logic work? What does it look like?

Real-world examples (perhaps in web application back-end domain?) would be very appreciated. [Here’s](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/messages/middleware.py) a corresponding example in OOP.

Comment: maybe? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching

Comment: Any examples other than abstract one-liners in Wikipedia article? I made sure to look up the term, I’m asking here because I haven’t found an answer to my question. :)

Comment: I got here after stumbling on the same line you've emphasized :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the [PEP-3119](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) article describes a solution to the [expression problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). The solution that they describe are [abstract base classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type).

To understand abstract base classes it will be useful to first elucidate the difference between abstract and concrete entities. An abstract entity has no implementation. A concrete entity has an implementation. Entities in object-oriented programming are usually either properties or methods.

A [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) in object-oriented programming languages is a group of concrete entities. Some object-oriented programming languages also have [interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming)) which are groups of abstract entities. An abstract base class is a mixed bag of entities. By default all its entities are abstract but they can be made concrete by giving them a default implementation, which can be overridden if necessary.

An example of an abstract base class in Java (correct me if I am wrong):

```java
abstract class Equals<T> {
    public boolean equals(T x) {
        return !notEquals(x);
    }

    public boolean notEquals(T x) {
        return !equals(x);
    }
}

class Person extends Equals<Person> {
    public firstname;
    public lastname;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname  = lastname;
    }

    public boolean equals(Person x) {
        return x.firstname == firstname &&
               x.lastname  == lastname;
    }
}
```

Anyway, moving on to the expression problem. [Philip Wadler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Wadler) has the following to say about it:

> The expression problem is a new name for an old problem. The goal is to define a datatype by cases, where one can add new cases to the datatype and new functions over the datatype, without recompiling existing code, and while retaining static type safety (e.g., no casts).

The expression problem is about all slicing and dicing data types into manageable pieces, while still allowing for the data type to be extended arbitrarily. A data type can be visualized as a two dimensional matrix of cases and functions. For example, consider the `Document` data type:

```
            Text       Drawing   Spreadsheet
        +-----------+-----------+-----------+
draw()  |           |           |           |
        +-----------+-----------+-----------+
load()  |           |           |           |
        +-----------+-----------+-----------+
save()  |           |           |           |
        +-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The `Document` data type has three cases (`Text`, `Drawing` and `Spreadsheet`) and three functions (`draw`, `load` and `save`). Hence, it has been sliced and diced into nine pieces which can be implemented in object-oriented languages like Java as follows:

```java
public interface Document {
    void draw();
    void load();
    void save();
}

public class TextDocument implements Document {
    public void draw() { /* draw text doc... */ }
    public void load() { /* load text doc... */ }
    public void save() { /* save text doc... */ }
}

public class DrawingDocument implements Document {
    public void draw() { /* draw drawing... */ }
    public void load() { /* load drawing... */ }
    public void save() { /* save drawing... */ }
}

public class SpreadsheetDocument implements Document {
    public void draw() { /* draw spreadsheet... */ }
    public void load() { /* load spreadsheet... */ }
    public void save() { /* save spreadsheet... */ }
}
```

So we have sliced and diced the `Document` data type into nine manageable pieces. However, we have chosen to first slice the data type into functions and then dice it by cases. Therefore, it is easy to add new cases (all we do is create a new class that implements the `Document` interface). However, we can't add new functions to the interface. Therefore, our data type is not fully extensible.

However, the object-oriented approach is not the only method of slicing and dicing data types. As the text that you emphasized says, there's another way:

> In particular, there is often a need to process objects in a way that wasn't anticipated by the creator of the object class. It is not always the best solution to build into every object methods that satisfy the needs of every possible user of that object. Moreover, **there are many powerful dispatch philosophies that are in direct contrast to the classic OOP requirement of behavior being strictly encapsulated within an object, examples being rule or pattern-match driven logic**.

In the object-oriented way **behavoir is strictly encapsulated within an object** (i.e. each class implements a set of methods and in our example above, the same set of methods). An alternative is **rule or pattern-match driven logic** in which the data type is first sliced by cases and then diced into functions. For example, in OCaml:

```ml
type document
  = Text
  | Drawing
  | Spreadsheet

fun draw (Text)        = (* draw text doc... *)
  | draw (Drawing)     = (* draw drawing doc... *)
  | draw (Spreadsheet) = (* draw spreadsheet... *)

fun load (Text)        = (* load text doc... *)
  | load (Drawing)     = (* load drawing doc... *)
  | load (Spreadsheet) = (* load spreadsheet... *)

fun save (Text)        = (* save text doc... *)
  | save (Drawing)     = (* save drawing doc... *)
  | save (Spreadsheet) = (* save spreadsheet... *)
```

Again, we have sliced and diced the `Document` data type into nine manageable pieces. However, we first sliced the data type by cases and then diced it into functions. Therefore, it is easy to add new functions but it's not possible to add new cases. Therefore, the data type is still not fully extensible.

This is the expression problem. If we slice the data type into functions first then it's easy to add new cases but difficult to add new functions. If we slice the data type by cases first then it's easy to add new functions but difficult to add new cases.

The expression problem arises because of an inherent need to extend a data type. If the data type never needs to be extended then you may use either of the two approaches (which I will henceforth call the object-oriented approach and the functional approach). However, for most practical purposes data types do need to be extended.

If you only need to extend a data type by adding new cases then the object-oriented approach is good (e.g. in graphical user interfaces the operations usually remain the same but new visual elements may be added). If you only need to extend a data type by adding new functions then the functional approach is good (e.g. practically all general purpose programs that I can think of).

Now, if a data type needs to be extended by adding both new cases and new functions then that's going to be a problem. However, it can be done in dynamic languages like JavaScript and Python using **inspection** (the word that the [PEP-3119](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) article uses). The only problem is that because it's a dynamic solution the compiler can't guarantee that you have implemented all the pieces of the data type and if you go back to the definition of the expression problem the last clause is **and while retaining static type safety**. Hence, dynamic languages still don't solve the expression problem.

Anyway, the PEP-3119 article talks about both **invocation** and **inspection** as means of selecting a piece of a data type. Invocation is preferred because if a function can be invoked it also means that it is implemented. Inspection is a dynamic solution and hence it is not always correct.

If you want to know how abstract base classes solve the expression problem then I suggest that you read the rest of the PEP-3119 article. For more information on the expression problem I suggest you read Bob Nystrom's blog post on “[Solving the Expression Problem](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2010/10/01/solving-the-expression-problem/)”.

Comment: Thank you Aadit, for such a comprehensive answer. Although, truth to say, it's still unclear whether in the PEP-3119 document, the authors were referring to the _expression problem_, as you've described it here. Nevertheless, it is a great answer.